# Download package from nexus server without maven

Tags: linux, nexus

Looking for ways of downloading a zip from our Nexus repo without the use of Maven. I'm trying to create a installation script that installs an assembly on a server.This server has a vanilla installation of linux. What options do I have?

Comment: A good ol'e plain HTTP request (which is what Maven does...)!?

Comment: "curl", "wget" all kinds of commands will download files over HTTP. See: http://blog.sonatype.com/2011/01/downloading-artifacts-from-nexus-with-bash/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any tools that can download a resource from webserver via HTTP. Beyond that for more powerful interaction with Nexus you can use any tool that can be used to work with a REST API.

So basically everything out there including shell scripts using e.g. wget or curl, any sort of scripting language like Ruby, Groovy, Perl, Javascript and so on as well as tools based on these like Chef, Puppet, Gradle, rake, grunt, Maven, Ant and so on and so on.

For a out of the box Linux server the simplest might be a bash script with curl but it really all depends on what you and your system administrator are comfortable with and want to use.